# Is using a JSON data type here appropriate?

Tags: mysql, json

I am using MySQL 8.0 and I have an ACL table, which has two columns int UserID and tinyint GroupID. They both form a composite primary key. 
A user can be in many groups, however there are only a few users who have such groups (administrators, moderators, etc.). 
I have to get the user's ACL groups when they log in, but because of that I have to perform two SELECT queries, one of User table and another of ACL table.

[image: ACL table example]
[image: User table example]

Would it be a good choice to change the data type of GroupID to JSON and store all group IDs of a user in one field? I could then use INNER JOIN and get all necessary data with a single query and UserID would become the primary key of ACL table. Are there any drawbacks to such a structure or perhaps better solutions?
I intend to mostly just use the SELECT operation on the GroupID field, UPDATE and INSERT would be rarely used.

Comment: *I could then use INNER JOIN and get all necessary data with a single query* You can doit using single query on current structuire too. *Are there any drawbacks to such a structure or perhaps better solutions?* in general the structure looks as optimal.

Comment: @Akina how would you do it with a single query? Simply joining the tables would result in getting repeated User row for each ACL row. I need 1 User row and all ACL rows that have a corresponding UserID.

Comment: Create a fiddle with some sample data (or post CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 5-6 users enough), and show desired result for this data.

Comment: @Akina Here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KQJAFP1f845pZ1g7SLbeA/1

Answer (score 1):

Simply no, with a single index on UserID you can easy and fast request the groups and delete also simlpy user from  groups.

That is all posible with json, but needs much more code and so can cause much more problems.

As long you don't need it in your application and also dont change it much, json is good to store a lot of data, but that is xml also.

Answer (score 0):

Look, maybe it is a query which you need?

```
SELECT `UserName`, 
       `Score`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`GroupID` ) groups_csv,
       CAST(CONCAT('[', 
                   GROUP_CONCAT(`GroupID` ), 
                   ']') AS JSON) groups_json_array
FROM `User` 
INNER JOIN `ACL` ON `User`.UserID = `ACL`.UserID 
WHERE `User`.UserID = 1
GROUP BY `UserName`, `Score`;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is any better than just having a JSON field in the first place? What are the advantages of using this method?

Comment: @user3757605 You may freely swap fields position and/or remove excess field(s). JSON  field is more difficult in manipulations (but you may of course). *What are the advantages of using this method?* One recors instead of several ones.

Comment: Is it necessary to group by every selected column? What if I have a high number of columns in my User table?

Comment: @user3757605 *What if I have a high number of columns in my User table?* List them all. Longer query text does ot mean more work to the server in this case. Alternatively you may use ANY_VALUE() function or temporarily change SQL server modse.